# Why isn't my JFrame displaying anything from my Jpanel?

Tags: jframe, jpanel

I'm working on creating a 3 man's morris board, but nothing is being displayed on the frame. It's empty despite having added my JPanel. Everything is fine if I used board = new JPanel(new GridLayout()); and do the following, but I wouldn't be able to draw the lines that would draw the board. I've looked over it a few times but can't seem to find a problem.

```
public class Project5 extends JFrame {

public final static int FRAME_WIDTH = 600;
public final static int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;

private JButton jb[] = new JButton[9];
private Board board = new Board();

Project5(){

    for(int i = 0; i<9; i++){
        jb[i] = new JButton();
        board.add(jb[i]);
    }
    add(board);

    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new Project5();

    frame.setTitle("Three Man's Morris");
    frame.setSize(Project5.FRAME_WIDTH,Project5.FRAME_HEIGHT);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

}

class Board extends JPanel{

public Board(){
    super();
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3,0,Project5.FRAME_WIDTH,Project5.FRAME_HEIGHT));
}


@Override
public void paintComponents(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);

    g.drawLine(0, Project5.FRAME_WIDTH, 0, Project5.FRAME_HEIGHT);
    g.drawLine(0, 0, 0, Project5.FRAME_HEIGHT);
    g.drawLine(0,Project5.FRAME_WIDTH,0,0);
    g.drawLine(0, Project5.FRAME_HEIGHT, Project5.FRAME_WIDTH, Project5.FRAME_HEIGHT);
    g.drawLine(Project5.FRAME_WIDTH, 0, 0, Project5.FRAME_HEIGHT);
    g.drawLine(Project5.FRAME_WIDTH,0,Project5.FRAME_WIDTH,Project5.FRAME_HEIGHT);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `GridLayout()` parameters : 
`GridLayout(rows,cols,horizontal_gap,vertical_gap)`

in your case, both gaps are 600 (`FRAME_WIDTH`, `FRAME_HEIGHT`) !

The buttons are displayed, but they are outside the panel, try to lower the gap,

i.e. : `setLayout(new GridLayout(3,0,0,0));`

You should see the buttons.

Comment: For some reason it isn't drawing the lines in paintComponent(Graphics g)?